# How to add css to template literals in ES6 with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, template-literals

I am trying to use the Material UI stepper in react.

The content of the step is setup as a string literal.

I want to add CSS (for paragraphs) inside the step content.

A lot of blog posts about this say that \n should work to make a br tag (for example: https://dev.to/sarah_chima/an-introduction-to-es6-template-literals-94l), however that \n just gets ignored when I try it.

How can I convert this:

```
function getStepContentResearcher(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return `para 1. \n para 2`;
```

Into two paragraphs:

```
function getStepContentResearcher(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return `para 1. 
                \n 
                para 2`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One simple way is to return an array.**

```js
case 0:
   return [`para 1.`, <br />, `para 2`];
```

**Another way is to use an inline component.**

```js
case 0:
      return <>para 1. <br />, para 2</>;
```

**Third way** is to provide style to the `Typography` or the content you are using with material ui `makeStyles`.

```js
instructions: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    whiteSpace: "pre-line" //<---like this
  }
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-new-line-fix-dd5yo?file=/demo.js) (includes all 3 options)

**full code snippet**

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  button: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  instructions: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    whiteSpace: "pre-line"
  }
}));

function getSteps() {
  return ["Select campaign settings", "Create an ad group", "Create an ad"];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return [`para 1.`, <br />, `para 2`];
    case 1:
      return (
        <>
          para 1. <br />, para 2
        </>
      );
    case 2:
      return `This is the bit \n I really care about!`;
    default:
      return "Unknown step";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css:

```css
white-space: pre-line;
```